# Tailwind css classes not applying in my component, till i take it to my page.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

tailwind is not working properly on my nextjs project, I have checked all my configurations but nothing checks out.
I found out it starts working when I carry my code from my navbar  component that appears to not work and put it in my page.js, the classes would apply, and if I go back to my navbar component to add more styles, everything would seem fine for some time then stop again, I have to carry my navbar code to page.js again for it to start working again.

**MY NAVBAR COMPONENT**

```
    import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'
import { BiSolidFoodMenu } from "react-icons/bi";
import { RiEBike2Line } from "react-icons/ri";
import { TbInfoOctagon } from "react-icons/tb";
import { TiContacts } from "react-icons/ti";
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
        <div className=' flex  items-center   w-full justify-around space-x-3'>
            <div>
                <h1 className='style '>
                    LUIGIE HOUSE
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div className='flex  space-x-3'>
                    <div className='flex flex-row items-center space-x-2'>
                         <Link href='#'>Home</Link>
                         <BiSolidFoodMenu />
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex flex-row items-center space-x-2'>
                         <Link href='#'>About</Link>
                         <RiEBike2Line />
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex flex-row items-center'>
                         <Link href='#'>Delivery</Link>
                         <TbInfoOctagon />
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex flex-row items-center'>
                         <Link href='#'>Contact</Link>
                         <TiContacts />
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                        Buy
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

**my tailwind config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
 
    
  ],
  jit: true,
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**my issue is that my tailwind classes don't apply on my project,until I take the code out of my navbar component,and put it on my page.js, then it works.Then i find out my classes are working now, so i go delete the code on my page.js and go back to my navbar component, only for my classes to stop working again after some minutes.**

**my folder structure**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pJee.png)

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code snippets of your code or a github link?

Comment: Sorry I had to edit my post to show my code.  @Dinuda

Comment: Did you add the Tailwind directives to your CSS?
```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: yeah,I installed the Tailwind while creating my next project, so it did all that.

Comment: Where is the Navbar located in your project? Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: @grekier just put an image link on my original post,please could you check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Check that you have the correct import statements in your global styles or wherever you include Tailwind CSS:

```
   @import 'tailwindcss/base';
   @import 'tailwindcss/components';
   @import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

NB*:Ensure these imports are at the beginning of your main CSS file.

-If you're still facing issues with certain classes not being applied, you can try explicitly including them in the safelist property. This ensures that Tailwind doesn't purge these classes during the optimization process:

```
    module.exports = {
  // ...
  jit: true,
  content: [
    // ... (as before)
  ],
  safelist: [
    // Add the classes that are not being applied in your Navbar
    'your-safelisted-class-1',
    'your-safelisted-class-2',
    // ...
    //Replace 'your-safelisted-class-1', 'your-safelisted-class-2', etc., 
    with  the actual classes that are not working as expected.

  ],
  // ...
};
```

After making these modifications, restart your development server and check if the issue persists.

Comment: wow!! it worked at this second step. thank you so much. 
could you tell me why I'm having the issue in the first place? cause if I have a lot of classes, I would have to put it down, maybe if I could trace the root issue and solve it, it might be better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have the Tailwind configuration looking in

```
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
```

However, your component is in `./public/components/Navbar.jsx` so Tailwind will not look there. So you can either change your Tailwind configuration to include the `public` folder or (recommended) move the components directory one level up.

I recommend number 2 as `public` is a special folder and the first solution might give unexpected results.